# Kafka Streams: Cannot resolve overloaded method

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am writing a Kafka Streams application in Scala. Whenever I try to use any method such as 'groupBy' or 'flatMapValues' I get a compiler message saying: **Cannot resolve overloaded method**

Kafka Streams is written in Java & it seems there's some issue calling its methods from Scala. Is there a way to get around this?

```
val builder: StreamsBuilder = new StreamsBuilder
builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input", Consumed.`with`(Serdes.String, Serdes.String))
       .groupBy((_, word) => word)
```

Answer (score 0):

When I started using these imports, it worked.

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.ImplicitConversions._
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.Serdes._
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.StreamsBuilder
import org.apache.kafka.streams.scala.kstream._
```